# Morris.js Donut with dynamic data from ViewBag

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, morris.js

have some questions regarding about **Viewbag(MVC)** & **morris.js**. I have found some information from here but none of them works. That's why I decide to posted this up.

I have a `ViewBag.ServicesData` variable stored data as below (table for easy reading)

```
Service    Count
----------------
Color      1
Cut        6
Massage    2
Perm       2
Spa        2
```

But I would like to populate this data into a **morris.js donut** chart. If I hard-coded it, the code will be like:

```
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut-example',
  data: [
    {label: "Color", value: 1},
    {label: "Cut", value: 6},
    {label: "Massage", value: 2},
    {label: "Perm", value: 2},
    {label: "Spa", value: 2}
  ]
});
```

my PROBLEM comes now, I have no idea how can I stored the viewbag data into an array that the `data: []` can accept and successfully display the donut charts? Thanks in advance.

**EDITED:** Finally, I figure out the **ANSWER** when I was trying different way of implementing

```
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut-example',
  data: [
    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.ServicesData)
    {
        @:{ label: "@item.service", value: "@item.count" },
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figure out the ANSWER when I was trying different way of implementing

```
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut-example',
  data: [
    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.ServicesData)
    {
        @:{ label: "@item.service", value: "@item.count" },
    }
  ]
});
```